# Handle cash flow in a database

Tags: database-design

What is the proper way to handle the cash income and expenses in a database?.

Example:

```
id, user_id, datetime        , value, flow (IN, OUT), notes
 1, 1      , 08/18/2012 16:35,  500,              IN, Invoice 0019
```

Comment: This is not a question we can answer here. There is no single proper way, and your question doesn't come close to laying out your particular requirements.

Comment: an example database for cash handle

Comment: This site does not hand out 'sample databases'. If you have a specific question or problem, post it. See the FAQ for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to look at some sample models to see how this is might be done, go to Database Answers.

http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/

some of these models deal with handling cash.  You can borrow ideas you get from these models in your own model.

Comment: the link no longer works